# NativeScript - iOS - get/list ALL photos in the user's shared photo library

Tags: ios, typescript, mobile, nativescript

I'm looking for an example of how, in NativeScript, on iOS, to fetch a list of all the photos (i.e. their filesystem paths) in the user's shared photo gallery (regardless of album, etc), with the intent that they will be rendered out in something like a ListView. Of course, this would include first requesting the necessary permissions to access it, if needed.

I haven't seen many samples on how to do this in nativescript, the closest I've found is this:

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-camera/blob/d68b7b6f8f11a47730304003fc8907ddee065716/src/camera.ios.ts#L211

Which is using `PHPhotoLibrary` to request permissions to access the photos, but stops there. The rest of the implementation in that library seems to be centered around accessing and using the camera directly.

Comment: You can not get file path of images, you will be given access to PHAsset only. Checkout [nativescript-imagepicker](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker) (which internally uses [QBImagePickerController](https://github.com/haiwen/QBImagePickerController)). You must be familiar with the native apis to customize the UI for image picker.

Comment: @Manoj thanks, yeah I assumed I probably wouldnt be able access the file paths directly, but with a PHAsset, would I still be able to render the photo in a nativescript view, or does it need to stay 100% within native apis?

Comment: Yes you may able to display PHAsset into image view using ImageAsset.

Comment: @Manoj would you be able to provide a snippet of how you would do so? Fetching the list of `PHAsset`s and creating `ImageAsset`s from them.

Comment: You will find the sample code for fetching albums and assets from photo library in the QBImagePickerController repo. To create ImageAsset from PHAsset, simply pass it as param to ImageAsset constructor.